# Custom report types for Accounts

Tags: custom-report-type

I have a requirement to show All Accounts without open Opportunities (also report should all accounts without any opportunities as well).

Below are the steps I followed:

1. I created a custom report type on Account (With or Without Opportunities) (which will result in all Accounts)
2. Then created a new report by selecting this report type
3. Added a cross filter " Accounts without Opportunities) (Until this point i am clear on the logic)
4. (I found this step in one of the training docs) Added sub filter on opportunity "Closed equals False"

It returned all Accounts without any associated Opportunities and Accounts without Open Opportunities

**My question:**

I am not clear on how the second filter works i.e "Closed equals False" on opportunity

Can someone please clarify and elaborate on how the above filter works and how it is yielding all Accounts without Open Opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

The first filter filters record by report type.

The second filter excludes closed opportunity.

This means all opportunities with stage different than closed should be included.